# Advantage of using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

JPA is a specification and hibernate is used to implement JPA specification but I have seen examples in many tutorials where JPA is not used which means we can work with hibernate alone. Please tell me what are the advantages of using JPA.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Hibernate implements JPA so it should also run in any JEE container.

Comment: internet search must be down right now I assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do decrease the degree of coupling to a certain orm tool, then jpa is a good choice.

It defines a set of well defined apis that you may use with any existing persistence provider.

Some projects require a specific persistence provider. Hence the jpa allows you to apply (not only) the basic orm mechanism even if you are not that familiar with the specific implementation. (I don't recommend to use tools that you don't know, but the jpa provides an abstraction an certainly lowers the entry barrier)